# ffmpeg arguments with flutter for video upload to firebase

Tags: firebase, ffmpeg, flutter, compression, firebase-storage

I have been trying to use ffmpeg to compress a videos file size  so I can upload to firebase storage.

I've ran the code on windows cmd and it works. But when i run it on flutter the quality of the video is terrible. I have also specified many values for the -crf param but the output videos quality and file size are always the same.

```
int processSuccess = await _flutterFFmpeg.execute(["-i", "file1.mp4", "-crf", "23", "fileoutput.mp4"]);
```

I had to change the package to video as the execution would fail on the default import as it could not find the -crf param.

```
  flutter_ffmpeg:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg.git
      ref: v0.2.1
      path: packages/flutter_ffmpeg_video
```

Am I doing something wrong with the execution arguments or is the import I'm using not the correct package. Sorry I'm very new to ffmpeg.

Thanks for the help.

https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using flutter_video_compress for compression. 
 Works well https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_video_compress

Comment: This should be unmarked as an answer, that package is no longer supported and won't compile on IOS

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using the `video` package of `flutter_ffmpeg` which unfortunately doesn't include GPL licensed libraries like `x264`. If you use a GPL licensed package like `min-gpl`, `https-gpl` or `full-gpl` then your output video will be encoded with `x264` and have better quality.

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter_ffmpeg package [21-packages](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg#21-packages) as per your requirement.

**Configuration**

In Android Edit android/build.gradle file and define package name in ext.flutterFFmpegPackage variable.

```
 ext {
  flutterFFmpegPackage  = "<package name>"//e.g "full-gpl"
 }
```